# how to generate PNG/JPG of excel range?

Tags: java, excel

how to generate PNG/JPG of excel range?
I need to send letter which contains content from sheet in my excel file like picture.

How I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: that is technically not a "screenshot" since it will be automated image generation and not appearing on "screen."

Comment: thank you for your comment. I changed the question

Comment: I would suggest you narrow your question down to "how to generate PNG/JPG of excel range"... the facts that you are using spring or emailing it afterwards are irrelevant. And asking how to email it means you are asking two questions not one.

Comment: the apache-poi tag is still relevant though. looks like no answers yet. it can be helpful to show what you have done already. i.e. the closest thing you found so far in the apache-poi documentation